# Delete all remaining observations from data frame when exceeding a specific value

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, conditional-statements, data-cleaning

I want to delete some observations from my data frame. For each individual (indicated by ID in the following), I have more than one observation and therefore more than one row in the data frame.

The idea is to delete all remaining observations for one individual, when they exceed a specific (pre-defined) value of time.

Here is some example data to explain the problem:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7)
time <- c(20,23,11,14,15,31, 14, 21, 7, 11, 45, 21, 35, 2, 90, 36, 18, 3, 35, 10, 5,19, 27, 12, 51,91,4,13,9,12,10,7,8,15,6,16)

sim_dat <- data.frame(ID, time)
```

Now imagine, my specific time-limit would be 30. Then I would like to delete all remaining observations for one individual, when it first exceeded the limit (and important: It doesn't matter, if the deleted values where less or greater than 30).

To be more precise: In the simulated data frame, ID 1 has 8 observations and exceeded the value 30 at his 6th observation. Now, the observations 6,7,8 of ID 1 must be deleted.

For ID 3 no observations should be in the final data frame, as ID 3 exceeded the value 30 within the 1st observation. On the other hand, ID 4 doesn't exceed the value 30, therefore no observations should be deleted.

I hope the problem is clear and I would appreciate any kind of feedback :)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Richie's comment-answer is [brilliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76921955/delete-all-remaining-observations-from-data-frame-when-exceeding-a-specific-valu/76921997#comment135603740_76921997):

```
library(dplyr)

sim_dat |> 
  mutate(flag = cumsum(time > 30), .by = ID) |> 
  filter(flag == 0) |> 
  select(-flag)
```

Output:

```
   ID time
1   1   20
2   1   23
3   1   11
4   1   14
5   1   15
6   2    7
7   2   11
8   4   10
9   4    5
10  4   19
11  4   27
12  4   12
13  6    7
14  6    8
15  6   15
16  7    6
17  7   16
```

Comment: Or just `sim_dat |> filter(cumsum(time > 30) == 0L, .by = ID)`.

Comment: that is perfection @RitchieSacramento! teaches me not to code while sleepy, I miss beautiful things like that 

Comment: Feel free to edit it into your answer - it's just your approach minus the sleepiness.

Comment: post it as an answer + I'll upvote u! :-)

Comment: btw how come you used `0L` instead of 0? Is it more about edge cases or am I missing something

Comment: ah fair! If you are interested in classes and types I'd recommend learning Julia. It's very similar to R, but with a type system which is much more fun + useful than it sounds

Answer (score 1):

Although I would use the `dplyr` approach proposed by @Mark, a base R approach may be useful to others that may have restrictions on packages. A (less-elegant) Base R approach would be:

```
sim_dat[unlist(tapply(sim_dat$time, sim_dat$ID, function(x) cumsum(x > 30) == 0)),]

#    ID time
# 1   1   20
# 2   1   23
# 3   1   11
# 4   1   14
# 5   1   15
# 9   2    7
# 10  2   11
# 20  4   10
# 21  4    5
# 22  4   19
# 23  4   27
# 24  4   12
# 32  6    7
# 33  6    8
# 34  6   15
# 35  7    6
# 36  7   16
```